# routevaluedictionary in actionline in asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on this project that I got recently. And I found following line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

I am little confused about the following:

```
new { area = "" }
```

on msdn it says its a `RouteDictionaryValue` but I need details what does this mean and what does it do?

Comment: If the current page is in the (say) `Admin` area, `new { area = "" }` sets the area to null and generates `href="/Home/Index"`. Without it it would have generated `href="/Admin/Home/Index"`

Comment: The type from anonymous (current one) will be used as RouteDictionaryValue since you are asked to have the same structure :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke what is area?i heard a lot but couldn't find any good source on net?

Comment: Its just a convenient way of organizing larger projects into logical modules. For an example a school site might have the main module for students to view information, and a separate Teachers area where teachers can update details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the

```
new { area = "" }
```

is an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level. The type of each property is inferred by the compiler.

Basically, it is accepted into the `ActionLink` as type object which is passed into the constructor of `RouteValueDictionary` at runtime, converting it into the proper type that is used natively in the `UrlHelper` class.

In other words, your `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", 
    new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

is equivalent to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", 
    new RouteValueDictionary() {{ "area", "" }}, 
    new Dictionary<string, object>() {{ "class", "navbar-brand" }})
```

with shorter syntax.

> What is `area`?

When a view is rendered, the [route values that are provided in the current request are the *defaults*](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346) if no value is provided in `ActionLink`.

Basically, Microsoft chose `area = ""` as the default value because if the parameter were instead set to `null`, you were to add an [Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) to the MVC project, and navigate to an action within that Area, the link generated would be to a controller named `Home` and an action named `Index` and also pass in the *area name* from the current request.

So for example, if you were requesting a URL in an area named `Admin` the link that is generated wouldn't go to the home page of the root of the site, it would try to find an `Index` action in a controller named `HomeController` *within the `Admin` area*. If that action doesn't exist in the area, you would get an error. The only way to generate a link out of the area is to specify it explicitly (such as `area = ""` or `area = "Foo"`).

> **NOTE:** If not using Areas in your MVC application, `area = ""` has no effect and technically can be removed. If no route values are needed to be passed to the request, you can either set it to `null` or use an overload that doesn't have a `routeValues` parameter.

Comment: what is area?can you add some info?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. But Microsoft set this default so you *can* add an Area without it affecting how your URLs are generated on the  layout view. If you need to generate a link to the non-area part of your site from within an area, you need to pass `area = ""` as a route value.